# Creating a custom square shape shader

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

I'm trying to create a custom shader in unity. Following is the code for my shader.

```
Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        struct v2f {
            float4 pos : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        // Default Vertex Shader
        v2f vert(appdata_img v) {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = MultiplyUV(UNITY_MATRIX_TEXTURE0, v.texcoord.xy);
            return o;
        }

        // Parameters
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float _FOV;

        // Alpha is the ratio of pixel density: width to height
        float _Alpha;

        uniform float4x4 _UnityDisplayTransform;

        // Fragment Shader: Remap the texture coordinates to combine
        // barrel distortion and disparity video display
        fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
            float2 uv1, uv2, uv3;
            float t1, t2;
            float offset;

            // uv1 is the remap of left and right screen to a full screen
            uv1 = i.uv - 0.5;
            uv1.x = uv1.x * 2 - 0.5 + step(i.uv.x, 0.5);

            t1 = sqrt(1.0 - uv1.x * uv1.x - uv1.y * uv1.y);
            t2 = 1.0 / (t1 * tan(_FOV * 0.5));

            // uv2 is the remap of side screen with barrel distortion
            uv2 = uv1 * t2 + 0.5;

            // black color for out-of-range pixels
            if (uv2.x >= 1.5 || uv2.y >= 1.0 || uv2.x <= -0.5 || uv2.y <= 0.0) {
                return fixed4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            } else {
                offset = 0.5 - _Alpha * 0.5;
                // uv3 is the remap of image texture
                uv3 = uv2;
                uv3.x = uv2.x * _Alpha + offset;

                return tex2D(_MainTex, uv3);
            }
        }
        ENDCG
    }
```

Im getting the following output with the same. This is the effect that I get when I apply the shader.

However Im desiring to get a two perfect squares instead of the curved edges. How can I be able to sort it out?

Comment: *`// uv2 is the remap of side screen with barrel distortion`* Hmmm...

Comment: @Draco18s i want to preserve the remap but just I would like to make it a square.

Comment: All the barrel distortion does is make it not square. Remove/alter the math that makes it not sqaure and it will be square.

Comment: I tried doing so with no positive outcome :(

Comment: atleast if it looks a bit like square, it would be fine

Comment: Again, that's what a [barrel distortion](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6CrL_1bHcn8) DOES. It makes it not square.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Shader "Custom/FakeAR"
{
    Properties{
        _MainTex("", 2D) = "white" {}
        _FOV("FOV", Range(1, 2)) = 1.6
        _Disparity("Disparity", Range(0, 0.3)) = 0.1
        _Alpha("Alpha", Range(0, 2.0)) = 1.0
    }

    SubShader{

        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            // Default Vertex Shader 
            v2f vert(appdata_img v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = MultiplyUV(UNITY_MATRIX_TEXTURE0, v.texcoord.xy);
                return o;
            }

            // Parameters
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _FOV;

            // Alpha is the ratio of pixel density: width to height
            float _Alpha;
            // Disparity is the portion to separate
            // larger disparity cause closer stereovision
            float _Disparity;


            // Fragment Shader: Remap the texture coordinates to combine
            // barrel distortion and disparity video display
            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR 
            {
                float2 uv1, uv2, uv3;
                float t1, t2;
                float offset;

                // uv1 is the remap of left and right screen to a full screen 
                uv1 = i.uv - 0.5;
                uv1.x = uv1.x * 2 - 0.5 + sign(i.uv.x < 0.5);

                //t1 = sqrt(1.0 - uv1.x * uv1.x - uv1.y * uv1.y);
                t2 = _FOV;// 1.0 / (t1 * tan(_FOV * 0.5));

                // uv2 is the remap of side screen with barrel distortion
                uv2 = uv1 * t2 + 0.5;

                // black color for out-of-range pixels
                if (uv2.x >= 1 || uv2.y >= 1 || uv2.x <= 0 || uv2.y <= 0) {
                    return fixed4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                }
                else {
                    offset = 0.5 - _Alpha * 0.5 + _Disparity * 0.5 - _Disparity * sign(i.uv.x < 0.5);
                    // uv3 is the remap of image texture
                    uv3 = uv2;
                    uv3.x = uv2.x * _Alpha + offset;
                    return tex2D(_MainTex, uv3);
                }  
                //float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);             
                //return 1 - color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Mind explaining what you did?

Comment: thank you very much. I tried it. It is showing me only one view. I was two squares on both sides.

Comment: In my picture, it is a bit curved across the edge. I'm trying to make two perfect squares adjacent to each others. Could you please help me in getting the corresponding effect?

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: I have added the screenshots

Comment: Please add a screenshot with my shader applied.

Comment: i have added the result after using your code. Kindly please check the same. It displays the feed in full screen. However, I'm trying to get an effect similar to what we have in the second picture.